# send notification to main device after push Imagebutton

Tags: android, push-notification

I would like to implement this function on my program, when the slave user push the imagebutton on the app, the slave send a notification to the main device and the main device update the database.
[image]

I tried to implement this by Dropbox, but is very hard to create and I think that there'isnt the best solution.
I have found this [articlie](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and before start to study this, I would like to know if this is the best way or not.

Comment: Yes, go with FCM. Though it's not always reliable and there might be some lag when you send the notification, it does the job.

Another solution would be to use sockets, but that might be an overkill for what you need.

Comment: How long is the lag? few seconds? or hours? Sockets is more simple?

Comment: It's usually instant, but sometimes you're gonna have a few seconds. At some point I had 5-10 minutes until I got the push, but it's rare. Remember that FCM doesn't guarantee you that the push will be received. Socket is a little bit more complicated to set up and requires more server work. As well, it might not suit your needs. Ex: if the app is gonna run in background, I don't suggest you use sockets, because the socket connection will be closed, eventually by the OS.